# Find the closest hour [javascript]

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a list of these items:

`hours = ['19:30', '20:10', '20:30', '21:00', '22:00']`

Assuming that now it's 20:18, how can I get the '20:10' item from the list? I want to use this to find the currently running show in a TV Guide.

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: Hi! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

First we should parse it to datetime in some way:

```
function parseTime(str) {
    var values = str.split(':');
    var hour = parseInt(values[0]);
    var minutes = parseInt(values[1]);
    var d = new Date();
    d.setHours(hour);
    d.setMinutes(minutes);
    return d;
}
```

```
var now = new Date();
var bestMatch = undefined;
var bestMatchDiff = undefined;
```

And finally:

```
for(var i=0; i<hours.length; i++) {
    var parsedTime = parseTime(hours[i]);
    var diff = Math.abs(now - parsedTime);
    if (!bestMatchDiff || bestMatchDiff>diff) {
        bestMatch = parsedTime;
        bestMatchDiff = diff;
    }
}
```

bestMatch would be the *closest* time. This is not the currently running show now. For that, you need to ignore times that are yet to come:

```
for(var i=0; i<hours.length; i++) {
    var parsedTime = parseTime(hours[i]);
    var diff = Math.abs(now - parsedTime);
    if (now<parsedTime) {
        continue;
    }
    if (!bestMatchDiff || bestMatchDiff>diff) {
        bestMatch = parsedTime;
        bestMatchDiff = diff;
    }
}
```

But keep in mind this might return `undefined` even if your list is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var hours = ['19:30', '20:10', '20:30', '21:00', '22:00']
    var diffrenceTime
    var selectedShow
    var d1 = new Date()
    var currentHH = 20
    var currentMM = 18
    d1.setHours(currentHH, currentMM, 0)
    hours.forEach(v => {
        var d2 = new Date()
        var hh = v.split(':')[0]
        var mm = v.split(':')[1]
        d2.setHours(hh, mm, 0)
        if (diffrenceTime == undefined) {
            diffrenceTime = d2 - d1
            selectedShow = v
        }
        if (d2 - d1 < 0 && d2 - d1 >= diffrenceTime) {
            diffrenceTime = d2 - d1
            selectedShow = v
        }
    })
    console.log(selectedShow)
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the currently running show (of course more validations need to be added):

```
const currentShow = hours[
  hours.findIndex(
    (c) => new Date(`01/01/2000 ${c}`) - new Date(`01/01/2000 20:31`) >= 0
  ) - 1
];
```

To find the next show:

```
const nextShow = hours.find(
  (c) => new Date(`01/01/2000 ${c}`) - new Date(`01/01/2000 20:31`) >= 0
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do something like this

```js
var originalArray =  ['19:30', '20:10', '20:30', '21:00', '22:00'];
var newArray = originalArray.map(i=>{
  return i.split(":")
})

newArray.forEach((k, idx)=>{newArray[idx] = parseInt(k[0]) + parseInt(k[1])/60})

console.log(newArray);

var time = "20:18".split(':');
var t = parseInt(time[0])+ parseInt(time[1])/60;
console.log(t);

var closestTimeIndex = 0, closestDistance = Math.abs(t-newArray[closestTimeIndex]);


for(var m=1; m<newArray.length;m++){

  if(Math.abs(newArray[m]-t) < closestDistance){
    closestDistance = Math.abs(newArray[m]-t);
    closestTimeIndex = m;
  }
}

console.log("colsest time is: " + originalArray[closestTimeIndex]);
```